# Android - Get Control of Gallery within my app

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery

Is it possible to get control of the android image gallery from within my app? I am able to open the gallery and the image below, but however, whenever I click the back button, it returns me straight to my app, but I want the back button to go back to the gallery first then back to my app so that the user have to click the back button twice to go back to my app

My code is below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media"), "image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

However with reference to the code below, I am able to allow user to go back to the gallery first then back to my app upon clicking the back button twice, but I am unable to allow user to open and view the image, meaning, once I click to launch the image, it straight away goes back to my app.

Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to start changing the ‘Back’ button, behavior, 
you need to override the onKeyDown() method and than check if the desired button has been pressed:

//Override the onKeyDown method

```
   @Override  
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {  
        //replaces the default 'Back' button action  
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
        {  
            //do whatever you want the 'Back' button to do  
            //as an example the 'Back' button is set to start a new Activity named 'NewActivity'  
            this.startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,NewActivity.class));  
        }  
        return true;  
    }
```

this code overrides the OnKeyDown() method, that is called every time a key is pressed. The if statement inside this method checks if the ‘Back’ button has been pressed. 
If it does, the code inside the block will execute.

```
@Override  
public void onBackPressed()  
{  
    //do whatever you want the 'Back' button to do  
    //as an example the 'Back' button is set to start a new Activity named 'NewActivity'  
    this.startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,NewActivity.class));  

    return;  
}
```

you can use your own activity and event into function .

want more use [Back Button Behaviour](http://www.41post.com/1685/programming/android-changing-the-back-button-behaviour)

let me know if you want any more help!!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. The problem I am facing now is that I am unable to display the image with the second code I have posted above.. Do you have any idea on how to do it? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I am happy to see that my answer helped you for first Question.
are you going to accept my answer ?
2)Second question just use ontouch event directly call your activity.
if you want more help share your code or description in brief.

Comment: The codes you have posted doesn't work... :( How do I call the method you have posted? & May I know how to start the code for ontouch event? Because I don't have that in my codes. How do I go about displaying the image??

Comment: for back button issue ..just read article that I already posted on my first answer.
and yes..code is working perfectly..I tested it...

IF you not sharing your code I will go for assumption on the event.

Comment: Because I am using the intent and not activity/class to start the system gallery, thus I want the full functions of the system gallery. But some part of it is not working as I have expected. :( The codes I have posted above are all that I have.

Comment: SORRY!!! The code you have posted works for the back button, however, my app has a tab layout, thus, when I am in the gallery the back button doesn't work.